# "Select a certificate" dialog not closing in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

In my Puppeteer script I want to close a dialog appearing after some interactions which is shown below

[image]

I have tried different things to close this dialog but nothing has worked.

I have tried below ones separately but nothing worked.

```
 await page.keyboard.down('Enter');
  await page.keyboard.down(String.fromCharCode(13));
  await page.keyboard.type(String.fromCharCode(13));
  await page.keyboard.press(String.fromCharCode(13));   
   await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    await dialog.accept();
   });
```

none of the above has worked, can you help me if this can be closed by someother code? Or if it is a browser alert

Actual code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: ['--lang="de-DE"']
    });
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    await dialog.accept();
   });
   await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Accept-Language': 'de'
  });
   await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  
   await page.click("#ID_secure18");
   await page.click("#btn_MethodNext");
// Tried all below ones:
  await page.keyboard.down('Enter');
  await page.keyboard.down(String.fromCharCode(13));
  await page.keyboard.type('Enter');
  await page.keyboard.type(String.fromCharCode(13));
  await page.keyboard.press(String.fromCharCode(13));
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await page.keyboard.up('Enter');
  await page.keyboard.up(String.fromCharCode(13));
  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await browser.close();
```

Comment: No these commands are not in order. I just listed what I already have tried.

Comment: I have added the full code here. Please check

Comment: Actually, looking at the screenshot, I think we're dealing with a Chrome browser certificate, different than an alert dialog. I think [#540](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/540) is relevant.

Comment: SPOT ON!
Thanks for pointing that out.  Issue was `await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});`
After removing it. I just used 
await page.keyboard.type('Enter');

Comment: Oh, glad that worked out. The `waitForNavigation` can hang the script. Feel free to [add a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you feel it'll help others.